# Does one Node.js thread block the other?

Tags: node.js

Using Node.js and one single CPU virtual instance, if I put a worker thread and a web thread on the same node, would one block the other? Would I require two CPUs for them to run perfectly in parallel?

Comment: What do you mean by a `worker` thread and a `web` thread?

Comment: They are just two separate node.js processes. One just does processing and the other serves web requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one would block another *if it is all synchronous code*.

Since you only have one virtual CPU instance (assuming not hyperthreaded), at the core level, the CPU only takes instructions in a synchronous fashion: 1, then 2, then 3, then 4.

Therefor in theory, if one worker had something like this, it would block:

```
while (true) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure whether the OS kernel would handle anything regarding blocking instructions.

However, Node.js runs all I/O in the event loop, along with tasks that you explicitly state to be ran in the event loop (`process.nextTick()`, `setTimeout()`...). The way the event loop works is explained well [here](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-event-loop/), so I won't go into much detail - however, the only *blocking part about Node.js is synchronous running code*, like the example above.

So, long story short: since your web worker uses Node.js, and the `http` module is an async module, your web worker will not block. Since your worker thread also uses Node.js, assuming it executes code that is launched when an event occurs (a visit to your website, for example), it will not block.

To run *synchronous* code perfectly in parallel, you would need two CPUs. However, assuming it is asynchronous, it should work *just fine* on one CPU.